# Connect to specific SSIDfor iPhone using QR code

Tags: iphone, qr-code, wifi

There are several sites generating a QR code to connect to a specific wi-fi network for Android: e.g. http://www.barcode.com/qrcode.html?view=qrcode

I am looking for similar feature for iPhone.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried getting this to work on Android and it seems different websites do this differently... is there any standard for Android and what app actually lets you use it if there is? ( http://www.qrstuff.com/ encodes the SSID/password/type on different lines where http://wifijoiner.appspot.com/ encodes them in JSON )

Comment: The "standard" (aka thing that seems to work) is a single-line string with a wifi header and fields split out: `WIFI:T:AuthenticationTokenHere;S:SSIDNameHere;P:WPA2;H:false;` Where`T=Token`, `S=SSID`, `P=Protocol`, `H=Hidden`. Certain characters need to be escaped with a backslash ... `\"'.:,;`

Comment: Also, you may generate an URL pointing to a "configuration profile" 
http://www.howtogeek.com/216137/create-a-configuration-profile-to-simplify-vpn-setup-on-iphones-and-ipads/

Comment: @Basic: I disagree with what you're saying, mate. The general encoding syntax is: WIFI:S:<your-SSID>;T:[WEP|WPA|WPA2];P:<password>;H:[true|false] - with S being SSID, T meaning authentication type, P password and H hidden (or not). Look here: [link](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#user-content-wifi-network-config-android) for details

Comment: @Beejay Looks like you're right. No idea if the unofficial "standard" has changed over the last 18 months or if I was just wrong to start with.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple standards out there. The one you showed above, and the one proposed by ZXing (https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#wifi-network-config-android) are some examples.

iOS does not allow apps direct access to the Wi-Fi settings so the only way to achieve this would be to generate a provisioning profile for iOS and have the devices visit that (you will need to different barcoes for Android and for iOS). This website shows that being done: http://getonmywifi.com/signup/

Update: As of iOS 11, the built-in camera can recognize the Wi-Fi codes as proposed by ZXing and use them to connect to Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 6):

At this point, it's not possible: Apple doesn't provide a public API to access wifi settings.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of iOS11 the stock camera app now recognises QR codes (including for joining a WiFi network). Safari can also recognize them in images - just tap and hold your finger over a QR code...

Also Apple's SDK has had support for reading 2D barcodes (QR,Aztec, PDF 417, Data Matrix) on iOS/OSX/tvOS for while - see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cibarcodedescriptor